# Looping the nested list?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to build a verification script which access the list of device under the main device and each devices should use the set of commands.

I would like to ask if what is the best method I could use to loop this for example if main device to internet device then check the device under internet the use the specified commands.

```
List Main device:
   1. Internet Device
      a. 1.1.1.1
    - List of command [show con, show 1.1.1.1]
      b. 1.1.1.2
    - list of command [show con, show 1.1.1.2]
   2. Private Device
      a. 1.1.1.3
    - List of command [show con, show 1.1.1.3]
      b. 1.1.1.4
    - List of command [show con, show 1.1.1.4]
```

Should I create a txt file for example for this or like a dictionary style? like for list of main device, devices, commands?

Should I use a nested list as well nest for loop to achieve this? or create multiple function?

I separate the list of command for other ussage. But let say for example i do have more that 5 device is my code is ok for this setup?

```
# sample code: #

internetdev = [1.1.1.1,1.1.1.2]
internetcommd = [[show con, show 1.1.1.1],[show con, show 1.1.1.2]]
privatedev = [1.1.1.1,1.1.1.2]
privcommd = [[show con, show 1.1.1.4]]

for intdev,intcmd in zip(internetdev,internetcommd[0:]):
    print 'Connecting to ',intdev ,'\nSending command ',intcmd
    child = begin_rmt(intdev,intcmd,uname,tpass)

for privdev,privcmd in zip(privatedev,privcommd[0:]):
    print 'Connecting to ',privdev ,'\nSending command ',privcmd
    child = begin_rmt(privdev,privcmd,uname,tpass)
```

Any suggestion? Also better if you could give like a sample code or reference so I can review. thanks

Comment: Have u run this code? You will get error on line internetdev = [1.1.1.1,1.1.1.2]
because the syntax is invalid. u should save it as string. '1.1.1.1' instead of 1.1.1.1 and also internetcommand list will give u same. Is show and  con different variables or a single variable?

Comment: If you are going to write these files by hand I would suggest yaml format. The you can decod it to a dict automatically

Comment: @Vishnu Chali, Sorry, I just write the sample codde but should be as a string format

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Nested Dictionary. Something Like,

```
devices = {
    "public": [
        {
            "name": "1.1.1.1",
            "command": ["show con", "show 1.1.1.1"]
        },
        {
            "name": "1.1.1.2",
            "command": ["show con", "show 1.1.1.2"]
        }
    ],
    "private": [
        {
            "name": "1.1.1.3",
            "command": ["show con", "show 1.1.1.3"]
        },
        {
            "name": "1.1.1.4",
            "command": ["show con", "show 1.1.1.4"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Thuvarakan, Tried that one and now studying the loop process using dictionary. I posted a ff. question regarding how to update the dictionary when match has been found maybe you could help me.